# How to login with Instagram OAuth 2.0 and display users feed? PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I'm trying to make a simple PHP script to allow a user to login with Instagram oAuth and display their account pictures.

Is there a simple and secure way of doing this without using outside plugins like I'm seeing on github?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.sitepoint.com/conquering-instagram-with-php-and-the-instagram-api/